# Zooming single product images in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, liquid

I'm configuring Shopify Timber framework: https://shopify.github.io/Timber/
I wanted to add zoom option to images on single product page. While zoom function works on main product image, it doesn't seem to update when different image is being selected. Hovering mouse over image always previews zoom of default one.

Here's the code:

```
 <div class="product-single__photos" id="ProductPhoto">
    {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
    <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg" class="zoom">  
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.product-single__photos').zoom({url: '{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}'});
    });
    </script>
 </div>

  {% comment %}
    Create thumbnails if we have more than one product image
  {% endcomment %}
  {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
    <ul class="product-single__thumbnails grid-uniform" id="ProductThumbs">

      {% for image in product.images %}
        <li class="grid__item one-quarter">
          <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" class="product-single__thumbnail">
            <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}

    </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

I'm using Jack Moore's zoom plugin: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Is there any way for java code to pick image source dinamically, or am I missing any Liquid variable?

Thanks,
Luca

EDIT:
Removing image source from javascript code didn't help either, it still shows default image:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.product-single__photos').zoom();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to iterate over each product photo:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".product-single__photos").each(function(){
        $(this).zoom();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain image resolution for all the images. The image resolutions should be at least 1200 x 900. Its working for me.

I have fixed it by set all image's resolutions as 1200 x 900

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add more details about how it works for you such as how you fix it ?

Comment: I have fixed it by set all image's resolutions as 1200 x 900